# How have an Android NFC service listening my app?

Tags: android, nfc, webhooks, data-transfer, google-appsheet

I have an app built in AppSheet (Google's codeless app building solution). My app can't use my device NFC (Android Smartphone), but it can work with webhooks. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to have a service running and listening on my device which I could post my data to be transfered through NFC (something like a server listening in localhost:8080). I did not find any solution to this yet.

Do you know any approach like this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a System NFC service already running on Android phones that handles all NFC interaction, you communicate to it via the Java/Kotlin API's.

I don't know if Google's AppSheet has a method to interact with the System NFC service many other languages/development platform do have.